# How model annotated methods should interact?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model, controller, annotations

I would like to know how controller methods should interact with `ModelAttribute` annotated methods.

For example `handlePage` method would like to filter the list created by `createList` method?
Or set the id for the object created by `createAnObject` method?

Is it possible or `ModelAttribute` annotated methods are designed to attach static data to the model?

```
@ModelAttribute("someList")
  public ArrayList<SomeList> createList() {
    return new ArrayList<SomeList>(100);
  }
@ModelAttribute("anObject")
  public AnObject createAnObject() {
    return new MyObject();
  }

  @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
  public void handlePage(Model model) {
    //Do some stuff to populate the model....
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two shouldn't really interact.  `@ModelAttribute`, in this context, is intended for exposure of reference data, i.e. data that doesn't depend on the details of the request.

If your handler method needs to modify that data, then `@ModelAttribute` isn't appropriate. Instead, the handler method should explicitly add the data to the model after modifying it.

Comment: Thank you Skaff, sorry for my ignorance, How do I add my data to the model in annotated controller?

Comment: @user648026: Using `Model.add`?

Comment: Ok got it, I need to change the method signature to accommodate the Model object as first parameter, 
so spring will set the model when calling the method (and then of course use model.add)
Thank you!